# Business Data List web part customization?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, bcs

I have a question with business connectivity services in SharePoint 2013. I have a connection with CRUD access using an SQL server. The list view displays all records, but I have use the Business Data List web part for searching through any records; however, the results displays a list of plain test.

Can anyone give me an advice or recommendation so the results have an option to Edit item, view item, delete item (as in the List Views, Default Style)?

Comment: Anyone has any ideas with the programming code to share the same style to edit records in the Business Data List web part??

Answer (score 0):

In general, CRUD actions such as Edit/View/Delete item features are based on the features that you incorporate int the external content type that you have used for the BCS external list. it has nothing to do with the display of the list.

I would suggest to re-verify the external content type once again and see if the actions are missing.

for further troubleshooting, **make sure the title or name with edit link fields are available in the view. those fields can be used for editing purposes. if not just enable them so you will be able see the edit icon.**

Comment: I have checked and rebuilt the external content type. I am not looking at the programming code so the style can connect to the actual List View (default style). I have he Business Data List web view working, but I am unable to edit any record.